# Writing python for Taiwanese stock market

Tags: python

I'm writing this.

```
>import stocker 
>stock = stocker(stockNo, df)
```

But, I keep getting this.

---

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-c4a4ee07c3f4> in <module>
      1 import stocker
----> 2 stock = stocker(stockNo, df)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I did include pip install stocker and I do have a stocker downloaded.
I am trying to make something like this https://weikaiwei.com/python/stocker/
but, whatever I did I just can't make it past step 4

I need help

Comment: thank you very much for your help to make it better for people to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You need to invoke a method/package within that module. You're calling the module at the moment.

```
import stocker
mystock = stocker.Stocker(stockNo, df)
```

https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker#getting-started for more help.

or as mentioned in the wiki you mentioned, you can import a specific class that you would need:

```
from stocker import Stocker
mystock = Stocker(stockNo, df)
```

Please note that the `stocker` is the package/module that you've installed and `Stocker` is a class within that package. They're two different things.

2. You have installed the wrong stocker module.As of now, you have https://github.com/jcamiloangarita/stocker installed as a pip package, which does not have any Stocker class. You're looking to use https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker and there's no pip package for this.

Please read the note section of https://weikaiwei.com/python/stocker/ to understand the pre-requisites and then place the `stocker.py` file present on github to the place where you're running the code from. Also, keep an eye about having an `__init__.py` file to make the module discoverable by python.

You would also need to uninstall the stocker that you installed via pip

```
pip uninstall stocker
```

Comment: So, I tried inputting the one you wrote for me, and when I run it. This showed up. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-de1cfa1bb61c> in <module>
      1 import stocker
----> 2 mystock = stocker.Stocker(stockNo, df)

AttributeError: module 'stocker' has no attribute 'Stocker'

Comment: I think you missed to post what's the o/p you had got. Could you please let me know ? Also, please note that these are two different lines and need to be entered separately if you're running it on a terminal or Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: thank you for your input. what o/p are you referring to if I may ask? I am very new and I don't really understand . i am running it on Jupyter notebook

Comment: Please ignore my comment. I added that before you've had edited your first comment. Updating my answer since I got to know the problem you're having. Please retry once again.

Comment: If you haven't noticed yet, the answer was updated. Please take a look back again and let me know how it goes.

Comment: it works!!! oh my god, you are a lifesaveeeeeeerrrrrrrr. Thank you very very very much

Comment: Glad I could be to your help :)

Answer (score 0):

MEANING OF THE ERROR -
The error simply means that stocker is a module name and it is not a function. So, you cannot use a module like a function.

SOLUTION HINT -
stocker is a module. You must use some function of stocker in the form stocker.function name. Visit the docs for the stocker or see your reference to get those functions.

Moreover, if you use the function directly, you may use -

```
from stocker import *
mystock = Stocker(stockNo, df)
```

Comment: I inputted the lines you gave me and it showed up with this. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-d00833878a53> in <module>
      1 from stocker import *
----> 2 mystock = stocker(stockNo, df)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Hey, the traceback simply shows that you wrote incorrect spelling while calling the function, you wrote stocker while the function/class is Stocker. Python is case sensitive man! Moreover, I am just giving example. The lines of code are bound to be correct. If they give incorrect result, then, check your question because I gave answer based on your question.